# Read binary raster files in R

Tags: r, binary, raster

I want to read binary integers in R and convert them into raster grids.
The files have the following charterers:

```
NCols= 4320
NRows= 2160
pixel-size: 1/12=0.833 degrees
upper-left-lat: 90.0-1/24
upper-left-lon: -180.0+1/24
lower-right-lat: -90.0+1/24
lower-right-lon: 180.0
nodata= -5000
scale-factor= 10000
datatype: 16-bit signed integer
byte-order: big endian
```

Here is what I do:

```
file <-"http://nasanex.s3.amazonaws.com/AVHRR/GIMMS/3G/1980s/geo81aug15a.n07-VI3g"
dat <- readBin(file,what="integer", size=4, signed = TRUE, n = NRows * NCols, endian = "big")
r <- raster(nrow=2160, ncol=4320)
r[] <- dat
```

But this doesn't seem to be right, I appreciate any suggestions.
.

Comment: Not really sure what you're after here, can you be more descriptive?

Comment: I think the data has subsets. Here is what I found from the documents: `Each NDVI data set is an INT16 file saved with ieee-big_endian
    it ranges from -10000->(10000->10004)
    with the flagW file added to the ndvi values as follows:
 ndvi3g = round(ndvi*10000) + flagW - 1;
 flagW ranges from 1->7
    to retrieve the original ndvi  and flagW values
  flagW = ndvi3g-floor(ndvi3g/10)*10 + 1;
  ndvi = floor(ndvi3g/10)/1000`
Do you know how I can retrieve the ndvi values?

Comment: @DNM Do you have a special interest in the precise file format of these files and want to understand those details? Or do you just want to end up with a raster so you can display it?

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14848/problems-with-na-values-when-reading-dem-file-with-r-raster-package-in-window/15093#15093) will help you out. This question is really more suitable for the GIS stack, you may have more luck searching [there](http://gis.stackexchange.com/). Good Luck!

Comment: @WhiteViking right now I'm just want to be able to properly make a raster grid out of them, then I want to re-project and analyze them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read such files with the `greenbrown` R package.

Install it in R with

```
install.packages("greenbrown", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
```

If that fails because the package needs to be rebuilt by its authors, an alternative is to first download the sources directly from the repo, and then install them manually, as explained in the [greenbrown installation instructions](http://greenbrown.r-forge.r-project.org/install.php). In the latter case you may also have to manually install a couple of packages that greenbrown depends on first: `install.packages` on `Kendall`, `bfast`, `strucchange`.

After installation, reading the raster from a URL is as easy as:

```
library(greenbrown)
r <- ReadVI3g("http://nasanex.s3.amazonaws.com/AVHRR/GIMMS/3G/1980s/geo81aug15a.n07-VI3g")
```

The object returned by `greenbrown::ReadVI3g` is a RasterLayer. We can display it with

```
plot(r)
```

which gives

[image]

Comment: it seems like an interesting package! but as you pointed the package fails to install.

Comment: @DNM It failed for me to, but I used `svn` to clone the repo on my machine locally, then installed the package "manually" following the installation instructions I linked to in the answer. (Straightforward, only takes a couple of minutes.)

Comment: thanks it works now! I built it under linux first then copied the package into windows environment. It seems that they created a function for these data sets, but I'm still interested to know how to read in the data manually. Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you like to understand the details of how to read the data manually, just have a look at the greenbrown package source code... The file `greenbrown/pkg/greenbrown/R/ReadVI3g.R` only implements `ReadVI3g()` It is well documented, nice and small and quite easy to understand. It uses `readBin()` too, just like you started.

Answer (score 4):

I built **greenbrown** from source (based on the files staged on [GitHub](https://github.com/rforge/greenbrown)) and found that it took considerably long to process one single file.

```
system.time(
  r1 <- ReadVI3g("http://nasanex.s3.amazonaws.com/AVHRR/GIMMS/3G/1980s/geo81aug15a.n07-VI3g")
)

#   user  system elapsed 
#  3.252   0.973 143.846
```

Therefore, I suggest to have a look at the **gimms** package which has been designed for this particular kind of data and, moreover, is available from [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/package=gimms). Note that in contrast to `ReadVI3g`, it does not offer automated quality control yet, but this feature is scheduled for the next version update. In the meantime, `overlay` from the **raster** package should be employed to discard low-quality values.

```
# install.packages("gimms")
library(gimms)

system.time({
  ## download file, see ?downloadGimms for further options
  f <- updateInventory()
  f <- downloadGimms(f[3], overwrite = TRUE) # download 3rd file in 'f', viz. geo81aug15a.n07-VI3g

  ## rasterize ndvi and flags
  ndvi <- rasterizeGimms(f)
  flag <- rasterizeGimms(f, flag = TRUE)

  ## perform quality control
  r2 <- overlay(ndvi, flag, fun = function(x, y) {
    x[y[] > 1] <- NA
    return(x)
  })
})

#   user  system elapsed 
#  4.538   3.894  26.781
```

The two resulting images are obviously identical

```
> unique(r1 - r2, na.rm = TRUE)
[1] 0
```

but as you can see, the **gimms**-based code performs much faster. Moreover, it offers parallel functionality (via **doParallel**) in case you would like to download and process multiple files at once.

Comment: Thanks @fdetsch! This is very interesting!